# Xunit unit test case c#

Tags: c#, xunit.net

I am developing a web API in Asp.Net core. I have written some code that retrieves data from the database using a dapper class with the repository pattern. I am passing along value to my constructor action as input parameter using `[FromRoute]` attribute inside the action I am calling another method, which expects an entity model object as an input parameter.

When I mock the function inside the controller action and try to pass the return type as a dummy object it returns a null object instead of the dummy object.

```
//I have the following controller action:

public async Task<IActionResult> GetProfileAsync([FromRoute]long ProfileId)
{
    BaseDto baseDto = new BaseDto();
    baseDto.ProfileId = ProfileId;

    var result = await _ProfileService.GetProfileAsync(baseDto);

    return Ok(result);
}

//Test Method
[Theory]
[InlineData(1237588858, 2)]
private async void Verify_If_Call_To_GetProfileCompleteStatusAsync_With_Valid_LoyaltyNumber_And_System_HasData_Returns_Ok_Status(long ProfileId, long DepartmentId)
{
    BaseDto baseDto = new BaseDto() {
        ProfileId = ProfileId
    };

    //arrange
    int statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
    ProfileService.Setup(m => m.GetProfileAsync(baseDto)).ReturnsAsync(GetDummyProfileData());

    MyController Mcont = new MyController(MockLog.Object, ProfileService.Object, MockSettings.Object);
    var Returns = MockMemberService.Object.GetProfileAsync(baseRequestDto).Result;

    //act
    var Myresult = await Mcont.GetProfileAsync(baseDto.ProfileId);
}

//Dummy Data Object
public ResultWithStatus GetDummyProfileData()
{
    List<ProfileDto> FindResult = new List<ProfileDto> {
        new ProfileDto {
            Flag=true,
            SourceId = 2301,
            CreateDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("2019-05-06 08:12:05.930")
        }
    };

    return Result.Ok(FindResult.SingleOrDefault(), ReturnCode.Read);
}
```

Note: All the mock object has been successfully mocked and initialized in test class constructor

I am trying to return the dummy object as a response. However, it is throwing the null value in `Myresult` object.

When I change my controller action input parameter as `BaseDto` object instead of `long` primitive type, It works. However, is does not work when I have long as input parameter.

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: What is the return type of `GetProfileAsync`?

Comment: As in `_ProfileService.GetProfileAsync`

Comment: What's the difference between, _ProfileService and ProfileService? Can you debug to see if the long value is being passed through each function correctly?

Comment: Can you share the controllers constructor(s)?

Comment: GetProfileAsync the return type of this function is ResultWithStatus this is a custom class sends the ProfileDto object and status code

Comment: public MyController(ILogger logger, IProfileService ProfileSer,
            
            ICommonSettings commonSett) 
        {
            // guards
           
            
            _logger = logger;
            _ProfileSer = ProfileSer;
            _commonSettings = commonSett;
        }